# Annotate a text with abstracts using DBpedia

Tags: javascript, dbpedia, spotlight-dbpedia

Is there any way to annotate a text using DBpedia spotlight (like the demo) and get as a result the text annotated with the abstracts of the entities(in json format or in href link) ? I am searching a way better in Javascript rather than in Java.